# macos x installion rapsberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

Hi I just installed my Pi according to this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Fe1C1D5DhU 
but I got just one MacBook so as I put the SD card back, it shows this error The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.Can you help me what to do please?

Comment: The easiest way to create an SD card on macOS for Raspberry Pi would be using a  small utility called [Pi Filler](http://ivanx.com/raspberrypi/), it is an automated script written in AppleScript. You will need a readable SD card though. Download the Raspberry Pi image from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/, and you don't even need to unzip it with Pi Filler, just run the Pi Filler and follow the instruction, it usually take about 5 mins to create an SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOTHING. `macOS` can't (it could but won't) read Linux formatted disks.

I don't know what you did (youtube is a no go area) but if you installed by any of the recommended methods https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ it should work if you put it in the Pi.

I also don't know WHY you would install Raspbian Jessie which is about to reach the end of its supported life.

Comment: macOS has no problem in reading the SD card created for Raspberry Pi, at least for the /boot directory.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve written your Pi image using an ISO image, which should have an extension ‘.iso’. That’s created the SD card filesystem in a form your Mac can’t read but which your Pi should be able to. So try inserting it into your Pi and see if it it will boot. If it doesn’t and the image is an ISO image then run Disk Utility on your Mac, reformat as an MSDOS FAT disk, check using the first aid tool and then flash the card again using your ISO download